# Regex match up to character unless character in between

Tags: regex

I'd like to use some regex to match the contents of some brackets and the text immediately after that until some whitespace, except in the situation that there is another opening bracket before reaching that white space.

For example in the following:

```
- (NSArray *)componentsForRegularExpression:(NSString *)regex
```

`(NSArray *)` and `(NSString *)regex` would be matched.

However using the regex I have already, matches `(NSString *)regex` correctly however rather than just matching `(NSArray *)` it matches the whole of `(NSArray *)componentsForRegularExpression:` which I do not wish it to do.

The regex I've used is as follows:

```
\(.*?\)[^\s|(]*
```

So how would I use regex to accomplish this, to match the contents of the brackets always but to only also match what is after it (up until whitespace) so longer as there is not another open bracket it that period?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
\(.*?\)([^\s(]*(?=\s|$))?
```

It matches something in brackets, then optionally matches any number of non-space non-`)` characters followed by look-ahead to match a space (or end-of-string, in case it may appear at the end of the string).

Note that there shouldn't be a `|` in `[]` (unless you want to match the `|` character).

[Live demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/4QTIDgT0nP) (surrounded by brackets and added non-capturing group (`?:`)).

Comment: And another, thanks very much. Giving you the ✔ for the extra detail!

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work for you:

```
(\([^)]*\)(?:(?![^(]*\()[^\s]*|))
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/opurflXx2E

Answer (score 1):

I see I ended up with much the same answer as [@Dukeling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1711796/dukeling). I did however manage to avoid lazy matching.

```
\([^)]+\)(?:[^\s(]*(?=$|\s))?
```